# What is road ahead for ArcGIS Runtime .NET/WPF SDKs?

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

Visiting Esri Developer [website](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/downloads/), I see two different sdks for .NET Developers.

1. [ArcGIS Runtime .NET SDK](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/)
2. [ArcGIS Runtime WPF SDK](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-wpf/)

I need to know the main differences between them.  If the first one (.NET) was introduced after the second one (WPF), is the wpf sdk going to be deprecated in the future?

Comment: WPF is Windows Presentation Foundation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation whereas .net is just .net. It depends what you're coding for as to which you need. I don't think that depreciation is going to happen in a hurry. I'd go with the .net for Visual Studio but that's because I'm used to it and haven't had any exposure to WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good background post about these SDKs (from ESRI) at http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/05/the-history-and-future-of-the-arcgis-sdks-for-net/

The transition (yep, also from ESRI) plan: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/03/07/getting-ready-for-the-new-net-sdk/

A couple of weeks ago, the [WPF SDK was deprecated](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/05/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-net-10-2-5-is-now-available/):

> Note that version 10.2.5 marks the last planned release of the ArcGIS
>   Runtime SDK for WPF. Technical support will continue to be available
>   through June of 2016. Moving forward, we recommend you explore WPF
>   solutions based on the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET.

So don't do new development on the WPF version.

Comment: Thanks Brad. So can we conclude that the Arcgis Runtime .NET sdk is a repack of wpf sdk and is better and with new features (.NET 4 async, task,...)?

Comment: From the second link: "You can consider the new Windows Desktop API an evolution of the existing WPF API, sharing many of the concepts and even many of the actual class and class member names. However it is based on a more recent version of the .NET Framework, takes advantage of modern patterns and practices such as MVVM and async Tasks and is built with the benefit of several years experience creating .NET APIs for developers." Its an incompatible change, but generally "mostly the same only better" (if you believe ESRI :-))